# Difference between Modernizr 2.X and Modernizr 3.0

Tags: modernizr

I read on the Modernizr site that Modernizr 3.0 is going to be a complete rewrite of Modernizr.

Questions:

- Where can I find the new Modernizr explained?
- Will V3 be backwards compatible?
- Can I find a complete pre-built Modernizer-latest.js for V3 anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where can I find the new Modernizr explained?

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/805

> Will V3 be backwards compatible?

No. That is why its a 3.0. Mostly yes, but not 100%. See the above link for release notes

> Can I find a complete pre-built Modernizer-latest.js for V3 anywhere?

http://modernizr.github.io/Modernizr/dist/modernizr-build.js

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. When will V3 be stable and ready for production?

Comment: I use it in production for over a year. We are really just nailing down the website at this point.